Raydium swap tracking
First of all I am new to Solana and Raydium (already build a dexsceener clone for Ethereum uniswap)
I am looking for some help to track swaps on Raydium, currently I do subscribe to the '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8', // Raydium Liquidity Pool V4
Check for ray_logs, any log with log_type: 3 or 4 I then decode.
const swapBaseInLog = struct([
  u8('log_type'),
  u64('amount_in'),
  u64('minimum_out'),
  u64('direction'),
  u64('user_source'),
  u64('pool_coin'),
  u64('pool_pc'),
  u64('out_amount'),
]);

const swapBaseOutLog = struct([
  u8('log_type'),
  u64('max_in'),
  u64('amount_out'),
  u64('direction'),
  u64('user_source'),
  u64('pool_coin'),
  u64('pool_pc'),
  u64('deduct_in'),
]);

export const logTypeToStruct = new Map([
  [3, swapBaseInLog],   // Assuming `log_type` 4 is for `swapBaseInLog`
  [4, swapBaseOutLog],  // Assuming `log_type` 5 is for `swapBaseOutLog`
]);

// decoded result
{
  log_type: 3,
  amount_in: 1000000000n, // amount that went into the pool
  minimum_out: 16010218519n,
  direction: 2n, // direction: 1 = base to quote, 2 = quote to base
  user_source: 1000000000n,
  pool_coin: 1239979198994n, // new baseToken liquidity (reserves) amount
  pool_pc: 21473529774465n, // new quoteToken liquidity (reserves) amount
  out_amount: 17260473921n // amount that went out of the pool
}

But at this point I am stuck as to which pool/token these logs belong to?
For the current project I am only interested in a few pool, not all, I do have a list of pools, but its to much to open a subscription for each pool.
ChatGpt is no help at this point, discord dev channel for raydium also no help, my last changce is posting a question here hoping that somone has some info to help me get to the next step.
Thanks.

1 You need to parsetransaction with signature to get the token mint adress in transaction.meta.postTokenBalances that is not wsol
2 To find the pool id (pair adresse) https://api-v3.raydium.io/pools/info/mint?mint1=${tokenMint}&mint2=${wSOL}&poolType=${poolType}&poolSortField=${poolSortField}&sortType=${sortType}&pageSize=${pageSize}&page=${page}`;
check the api of raydium here section pool : https://api-v3.raydium.io/docs/


use
transaction = await connection.getTransaction(signature, {
commitment: "confirmed",
maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
});


Sorry, but this is not what I need. A transaction contains all data I assume? so it's ok to get the transaction data, but I can not nor want to depend on raydium api/sdk. I need to know how solana transactions can be decoded to get the data I need.

According to the first question, Mayga Fatmawati talk about log with ray_logs that is catch, that's why I propose to use raydium api to have pool id. Depending on what is on log, you need to adapt to catch every possibilities
